# What grammar rule is this? (Commas)

Tags: commas

- a detective club consisting of teens specializing in solving mysteries → each teen is great at solving mysteries
- a detective club consisting of teens, specializing in solving
  mysteries → the detective club as a whole is all about solving
  mysteries (but perhaps one of the members—say, Shaggy—isn't so great
  at solving mysteries)

Trying to explain how a comma can change the meaning of a sentence in subtle ways. In this case, the comma changes what specifically is being referred to (the club as a whole vs all the teens within the club). Would this be a matter of restrictive vs non-restrictive phrases? (The latter requiring a comma?)

Comment: It's about whether the adjectival phrase "specializing in solving mysteries" modifies the club or the teens. I'm not sure if there is a specific name for this.

Comment: You might find some relevant stuff by looking up the phrase "attachment ambiguity". But that doesn't specifically indicate that the presence or absence of a comma removes the ambiguity.

Comment: Notice that if you pronounce the two sentences, you'd use different intonation patterns. That's what the comma attempts to symbolize.

Comment: Post the whole sentence otherwise we have to do in mentally and that means we have to work for you.

Comment: The comma indicates grouping. << a detective club consisting of teens specializing in solving mysteries → a detective club consisting of {teens specializing in [solving mysteries]} .>> // << a detective club consisting of teens, specializing in solving mysteries → a detective club {consisting of teens},  [_and_] {specializing in solving mysteries} .>> As J Lawler says, in speech, the pause pattern would indicate grouping.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a native, alternative option (as a full sentence):

> It's a detective club for teens, where they solve mysteries.

I echo the comments about the limited use of participle clauses by native speakers, particularly in speech and in informal or semi-formal writing. They can be helpful in academic writing or for advanced students who need high scores in writing tests, for example, to show a range of grammatical options for introducing consequences.

In my experience, some learners import participle clauses from their native language, applying different grammatical rules to English.

Answer (score -1):

> <s>Trying</s> **I am** trying to explain how a comma can change the meaning of a sentence in subtle ways.

Excessive use of participles often gives rise to ambiguity as they often have no obvious subject or tense. Native speakers do not often use participle phrases. Students think participles are common because a lot of time is spent learning them - they are not common.

You need to give a complete sentence. Both of your examples are phrases without an active verb...

> Would this be a matter of restrictive vs non-restrictive phrases? (The latter requiring a comma?)

Yes, but (a) these participle phrases are known as reduced relative clauses, (b) note where the commas are.

> 1. A detective club **, **consisting of teens**,** specializing in solving mysteries opened last week in our town. -> the detective club that specializes in solving mysteries opened last week. Incidentally, the members appear to be teens.

**consisting of teens** and the commas can be omitted as no important information has been lost.

> 2. A detective club consisting of teens specializing in solving mysteries opened last week in our town.

{A detective club that consists of teens that specialize in solving mysteries} This is a single noun phrase and is the subject of the sentence.

"that consists of teens that specialize in solving mysteries" is the relative clause. It is defining.

Comment: +1 for "Students think participles are common because a lot of time is spent learning them". I've long suspected something similar in relation to Perfect verb forms - except there I think maybe the TEFL *teachers* always make a point of spending time on that because it's one of the few aspects of English usage ***they** [mistakenly] **think are easy to explain***.

Comment: Inflections. They spend hours learning inflections that native speakers ignore. English is more like Chinese than Latin.

Comment: The old unrestrictive relative clauses not containing important information platitude is a load of baloney! Consider: “I’ve just spoken to the police, who have arrested your wife.”

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. “I’ve just spoken to the police, who have arrested your wife.” -> 1. I have spoken to the police. The police have arrested your wife. -> Separate independent clauses; not necessarily even the same force/officers. -- “I’ve just spoken to the police that have arrested your wife.” *that have arrested your wife* defines the force to whom you spoke. That is important.

Comment: No, the example I gave does not involve an integrated relative clause. But to make the point crystal clear: "I just met Greybeard, who has shopped you to the police for the diamond heist." (Not my dv, btw)

Comment: Whenever I see that comma, which indicates a pause, I always add to the clause: "I just met Greybeard, who, ***by the way*** has shopped you to the police", i.e. my shopping them is not diectly connect to the meeting.